# AWK command cut the file name

Tags: awk, filenames

```
fileName=20201211-v1-ABC144_newrecords_2020-12-10_12-51-32-000_2444_511
fName1=$(echo $fileName | awk -F"-" '{ print $3 }')
```

CUT the file name from $3 to until date value

I need file name to be like this :

```
ABC144_newrecords_2020-12-10_12
```

Answer (score 4):

To extract part of strings following a pattern, you can use `expr`:

```
expr " $fileName" : '[^-]*-[^-]*-\(.*_[0-9]\{4\}-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]\)_'
```

(here extracting the part after the second `-` and up to the rightmost occurrence of `_YYYY-MM-DD_` (trailing `_` not included))

Or with `zsh`:

```
set -o extendedglob
[[ $fileName = (#b)[^-]#-[^-]#-(*_[0-9](#c4)-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9])_* ]] &&
  print -r - $match[1]
```

Or:

```
set -o rematchpcre
[[ $fileName =~ '^.*?-.*?-(.*_\d{4}-[01]\d-[0-3]\d)_' ]] &&
  print -r - $match[1]
```

Or with `ksh93`:

```
printf '%s\n' "${fileName/#*([^-])-*([^-])-@(*_{4}(\d)-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9])_*/\3}"
```

Or with `bash`:

```
[[ $fileName =~ ^[^-]*-[^-]*-(.*_[0-9]{4}-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9])_ ]] &&
  printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is probably using cut:

```
printf '%s\n' "$fileName" | cut -d- -f3-5
```

This just sets the delimiter to “-“ and extracts fields 3-5.

It assumes the file name doesn't contain whitespace characters.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want to delete the two first and last three strings delimited by a dash (`-`) from the value `$fileName`.  This is most efficiently done with a parameter substitution ("efficient" = does not use any external program, just the shell).

```
$ fileName=20201211-v1-ABC144_newrecords_2020-12-10_12-51-32-000_2444_511
```

```
$ fileName=${fileName#*-*-}
$ echo "$fileName"
ABC144_newrecords_2020-12-10_12-51-32-000_2444_511
```

```
$ fileName=${fileName%-*-*-*}
$ echo "$fileName"
ABC144_newrecords_2020-12-10_12
```

The substitution `${fileName#*-*-}` will be the value `$fileName` but with the bit that matches the pattern `*-*-` at the start removed.  In a similar manner, `${fileName%-*-*-*}` will be `$fileName` but with the bit that matches `-*-*-*` at the end removed.